# Password masking custom field in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have Created the Custom Form in the Orchard CMS in which i have created one field for Password. But when i enter the password it do not get Mask. I want to Mask the Password enter by user. I have enabled Custom Field module in Orchard Module. But still i am not getting the exact solution for it. Please help me to get out of this..

Comment: Please set my reply as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in password content field in Orchard.

You could however use a Text Field on the content type of your choice to store the password. Then, enable the [Shape Tracing](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools) feature, hover over the generated Text Field editor and create an [alternate](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates) for it (as specific as possible, so it will be used just for that field). With this alternate in your theme you can override the html of the field and change the text field's editor to that of a password input box.